# React Native - TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'prototype' of function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs, ts-jest

Jest Unit tests are failing after updating the React Native version to 0.71.7 with the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'prototype' of function 'function NetworkError(message, code) {
      var name = arguments.length > 2 && arguments[2] !== undefined ? argume...<omitted>...
    }'

      19 |   }
      20 | }
    > 21 | NetworkError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

Failed unit tests increase if I remove line 21. Line 21 was added to work around circular dependency to make tests work in previous React Native versions.

NetworkError handles the errors in the app

```
export class NetworkError {
  public message: string | null;
  public name: string;
  public code: number;

  constructor(
    message: string | null,
    code: number,
    name: string = 'NetworkError',
  ) {
    this.message = message;
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
  }
}
NetworkError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

Package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.10",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
```

Attempts:

1. use Object.defineProperty
2. remove line 21

So, how can I refactor this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the old way of using inheritance in JavaScript if you use `class` use `extends` not `prototype`:

```js
export class NetworkError extends Error {
  public message: string | null;
  public name: string;
  public code: number;

  constructor(
    message: string | null,
    code: number,
    name: string = 'NetworkError',
  ) {
    this.message = message;
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
  }
}
```